# Attaching functions on an instance of an element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

We can modify a DOM element and add to its prototype. For example, if we want to add something only to the canvas, we'd do something like this:

```
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.doSomething = function(arg) { ... };
```

We can then perform this action on a canvas element:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasId');
canvas.doSomething(...);
```

Is it possible to add/attach a function to this instance of the canvas without modifying the prototype of HTMLCanvasElement. I only want a canvas where doSomething(...) was called to have access to the additional methods, not all canvas elements in the DOM. How can I do this?

I've tried the following in my doSomething function:

```
this.prototype.foobar = function() {...}
```

However, prototype is undefined here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Shusl helped me come up with the correct answer. It was easier than I thought. In my doSomething(args) function, instead of trying to modify the object prototype, I just directly attached the function. Here's the full source code:

```
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.doSomething = function(args) {
    this.foobar = function(args) { ... };
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasId');
canvas.doSomething(...);
canvas.foobar(...);
```

Now, foobar is only accessible to the instance of the canvas where doSomething was called. At the same time, I don't have to have any information about the instance.

Comment: This way all instance can have foobar if they call doSomething.

Comment: Might want to add a check to see if `this.foobar` already exists before setting it. That way, every time they call `doSomething`, it doesn't re-set `this.foobar`.

Comment: What you really want is an `.extend` method: [Prototype's `Element.extend`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/extend), [`jQuery.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) ([John Resig article](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/)), [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/YUI.html#method_extend), [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-extend), etc.

Answer (score 11):

In that case, you can directly attach a `method` to your canvas object:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasId');
canvas.doSomething= function() {...}; ///doSomething will only be available to this particular canvas.
canvas.doSomething(...);
```

Comment: doSomething is working just fine. I want to be able to attach another method/function. However, I won't necessarily know which object I'm attaching to. I won't have access to the "canvas" object.

Comment: Although, your answer wasn't correct but your response helped me get to the answer. Voted up!

Comment: You can attach a Identifier to the canvas object or you can keep the reference of particular canvas. And access to that canvas whenever you want. You can attach any number of method to a object.

Answer (score 8):

With jQuery, you can use the `data` property.

```
//setting the function
$('element').data('doSomething', function(arg) { ... });
//calling the function
$('element').data('doSomething')(arg);
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FgapU/)**

Answer (score 3):

`Object.defineProperty(element, 'doSomething', {value:function(arg){ ... }}  );`

Where '**element**' is the element you want to add the property to,
'**doSomething**' is the name and the 
third argument is an object of the property its self. In your case a function.

For example:

```js
var mycanvas = document.createElement("canvas");

Object.defineProperty(mycanvas, 'doSomething', {
  value: function(x){console.log(x); },
  configurable: true 
});

mycanvas.doSomething('my message');
//prints 'my message' to the console.
```

The 'configurable' property specifies if you would like the 'doSomething' property to be able to be changed again after it is created. Check out the [MDN Details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) for more information and examples.